# What is this phantom force pushing my header content over to the right?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/nWqYL/2/embedded/result/

I've been working on fixing some issues with this prototype site. Myself and our web designer have spent countless hours trying to figure out why the content in the header is getting pushed to the right(In this case, its the logo, but happens with text also)

I'm thinking this might have to do with Twitter Bootstrap's columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try to isolate the problem in your fiddle, and break up your code into given regions as much as possible, not just put everything in a fiddle. If nothing else, trying to isolate the problem can get you a better idea of what the problem is not, and keep us from having to guess what css file to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went ahead and foundthe problem that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<div class="headerleft">`: ended up being the culprit.
I have to mess with the positioning on it more.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be the positioning ?

Have you tried that instead :

```css
#headerright {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: -22px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nWqYL/4/) ([full size](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/nWqYL/4/show/))

Comment: That wasn't the issue, it had to deal with the logo.